# Please explain why the second loop does not replace the other letters with "("

Tags: javascript

```js
function duplicateEncode(word) {
  var components = word.split("")
  var empty = []
  var emptyI = []
  for (var i = 0; i < components.length; i++) {
    if (empty.indexOf(components[i]) == -1) {
      empty.push(components[i])
      emptyI.push(components[i])
    } else if (empty.indexOf(components[i]) > -1) {
      empty.push(")");
    }
  }
  console.log(empty)
  console.log(components.length)
  for (var j = 0; j < components.length; j++) {
    if (empty[j] == emptyI[j]) {
      console.log(empty[j], emptyI[j], empty, emptyI, j, components.length)
      empty.splice(empty[j], 1, "(")
      emptyI.splice(empty[j], 1, "(")
    }
  }
  return empty;
}

console.log(duplicateEncode("din"))
```

I realize that I could what I'm attempting with ES6 methods, but I'm trying to do this with "vanilla" javascript. I don't understand why the second for loop isn't replacing all the letters within the the if statement. So, if you could shed some light on what I"m overlooking I would greatly appreciate it. Many thanks

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that includes proper explanation of what this code should do and provide sample input and expected results

Comment: @charlietfl, expected output is here... code is here... verifiable example is here... if you don’t have anything to say, please say nothing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second loop, these lines:

```
empty.splice(empty[j], 1, "(")
emptyI.splice(empty[j], 1, "(")
```

For the first parameter to [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) you're passing the array element, in this case a string—NOT the index of the array you wish to replace.

Try:

```
empty.splice(j, 1, "(")
emptyI.splice(j, 1, "(")
```

...here I'm passing the current index of the array loop, `j`.

From the provided [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) link:

> array.splice(start[, deleteCount[, item1[, item2[, ...]]]])
>
> `start`
>      Index at which to start changing the array (with origin 0). If greater than the length of the array, actual starting index will be set to the length of the array. If negative, will begin that many elements from the end of the array (with origin -1) and **will be set to 0 if absolute value is greater than the length of the array**.

Comment: Ah, that makes complete sense! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to splice should be a positional index, not an argument.  Perhaps you mean to do:

```
empty.splice(j, 1, "(")
```